# Link to find collection items from second collection very slow

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Please let me know if this is already answered somewhere; I can't find it.

In memory, I have a collection of objects in firstList and related objects in secondList. I want to find all items from firstList where the id's match the secondList item's RelatedId. So it's fairly straightforward:

```
var items = firstList.Where(item => secondList.Any(secondItem => item.Id == secondItem.RelatedId));
```

But when both first and second lists get even moderately larger, this call is extremely expensive and takes many seconds to complete. Is there a way to break this up, or redesign it into multiple queries to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this code is so inefficient is that for every element of the first list, it has to iterate over (in the worst case) the entirety of the second list to look for an item with matching id.
A more efficient way to do this using LINQ would be using the `Join` method as follows:

```
var items = firstList.Join(secondList, item => item.Id, secondItem => secondItem.RelatedId, (item, _) => item);
```

If the second collection may contain duplicate IDs, you will additionally have to run `Distinct()` (possibly with some changes depending on the equality semantics for the members of the first list) on the result to maintain the semantics of your original code.

This code resulted in a roughly 100x speedup for me with a test using two lists of 10000 elements each.

If you're running this operation often and one of the collections does not change, you could consider caching the `Id`s or `RelatedId`s in a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: My results aren't close to 100x faster; perhaps like 10x, but that may be because of a lot of .ToString() required on the ID's. The model was from Swagger generation, and I think the source team defined Guids incorrectly in their API as they come back as JsonElement 'object' and not actually a GUID. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯